# Como fazer update de campos com campos de outra tabela?

Tags: mysql, sql, query, sql-update

Não estou conseguindo atualizar uma tabela com o select de outra.

Tenho uma tabela `mdl_user` que contém várias colunas e criei outra `users_sg` para copiar algumas colunas.

Copiei com

```
INSERT INTO
  users_sg (id, username, firstname, lastname)
SELECT
  id, username, firstname, lastname FROM mdl_user
```

Queria ficar atualizando, mas só consegui fazendo uma coluna e um usuário por vez:

```
UPDATE
  users_sg
SET
  users_sg.username = (SELECT username FROM mdl_user where id=3)
WHERE id=3
```

Tenho como atualizar os campos `username`, `firstname` e `lastname` de todos os usuários de uma vez?

Comment: A atualização será periódica, ou quando for alterada em uma tabela você quer que atualize automaticamente na outra?

Comment: @CelsoMarigoJr acho que é para fazer uma vez só.

Comment: @JorgeB. mas nesse caso o insert ja resolveria não!?

Comment: @CelsoMarigoJr pois talvez, está um bocado confuso. Fabio podes explicar?

Comment: A resposta ajudou?

Comment: Oi, precisarei rodar o comando pelo menos uma vez por dia para atualizar os que já existem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode fazer um [UPDATE COM JOIN](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-update-join/) com as duas tabelas para atualizar as 3 colunas, user o where caso seja de um único registro que tenha que ser alterado.

```
UPDATE users_sg as sg 
join mdl_user as user_ on user_.Id = sg.Id
SET sg.username = user_.username,
sg.firstname = user_.firstname,
sg.lastname = user_.lastname;
-- where user_.Id = 3 -- caso seja só de um unico registro mais com os 3 campos.
```

Para fazer isso automaticamente terá que usar um evento.

```
DELIMITER $
CREATE EVENT AtualizaTabela 
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
    STARTS NOW()
    DO BEGIN 
            UPDATE users_sg as sg 
            join mdl_user as user_ on user_.Id = sg.Id
            SET sg.username = user_.username,
            sg.firstname = user_.firstname,
            sg.lastname = user_.lastname;
    END
$ DELIMITER
```

Comment: Nesse exemplo Goku eu iria conseguir atualizar apenas 1 usuário por vez, correto? Eu precisaria atualizar todos de uma vez.

Comment: Sem o Where você atualizará todos Onde os ids são iguais

Comment: Entendi Goku, seria isso mesmo, porém tentei rodar esse comando agora  e ele da o seguinte erro:
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from users_sg sg 
join mdl_user user_
on user_.id = sg.id' at line 5

Comment: Ponto e vírgula no final dos comandos

Comment: Oi, coloquei o ponto e virgula, ficou assim:
UPDATE sg
SET sg.username = user_.username,
sg.firstname = user_.firstname,
sg.lastname = user_.lastname;
from users_sg sg;
join mdl_user user_;
on user_.Id = sg.Id;

Mas o erro foi: #1146 - Table 'baseteste.sg' doesn't exist;

Ele tenta criar uma outra tabela? Não era pra atualizar a users_sg?

Comment: Veja a edição,  você colocou  **;**  dentro do comando os **;** tem que ser no final de cada comando tipo `select * from tabela ;`

Comment: Goku, desculpe, mas não estou compreendendo, rodei no phpmyadmin dessa forma:

`UPDATE sg
SET sg.username = user_.username,
sg.firstname = user_.firstname,
sg.lastname = user_.lastname;
from users_sg sg;
join mdl_user user_;
on user_.id = sg.id;`

Veja que coloquei o ; no final de cada instrução (SET, from, join, on), o que fiz errado?

Comment: Não, o ponto e virgula tem que ser no final de tudo.. on user_.id = sg.id; <-- aqui.

Comment: Ah sim, eu tinha feito isso também. Mas o erro é: 

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from users_sg sg 
join mdl_user user_
on user_.id = sg.id' at line 5

Comment: Vacilo meu, o mysql é diferente a sintaxe. editei a pergunta

Comment: Goku, sem palavras, muito obrigado...